# Are there any Christian Churches or communities that teach same-sex marriage is a right? On what biblical basis?

Tags: biblical-basis, same-sex-marriage, human-rights

Are there any Christian Churches or communities that teach same-sex marriage is a right? On what biblical basis do they base their teaching?

A couple of examples will do for an answer.

Comment: The Golden Rule?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Community of Christ](http://www.cofchrist.org/USAconf/USANatlConf04-21-2013.pdf)

Their statement of note:

> The 2013 USA National Conference recommends the sacrament of marriage be extended, where legal in the USA, to persons of the same sex/gender. Thus the 2013 USA National Conference recommends a change to the current policy for the USA on the sacrament of marriage;

And the above recommendation was recently [approved](http://www.cofchrist.org/usaconf/).

Here is their basis for it (though not explicitly Biblical):

> We believe this is where God is directing Community of Christ, to be an inclusive body where everyone is welcome <sub>[source](http://www.kshb.com/news/region-missouri/independence/community-of-christ-church-to-allow-same-sex-marriages-commitment-ceremonies)</sub>

This [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Christian_denominational_positions_on_homosexuality) page lays it out pretty well which Christian denominations accept same-sex marriage and just *how much* they accept it. Some denominations just kind of accept a little, while others split over it.